# gmusicbrowser -cmd ShowHide doesn't open on top of windows when using a custom shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, gmusicbrowser

When I run `gmusicbrowser -cmd ShowHide` from the terminal gmusicbrowser opens on top of all windows.
When I run it from a custom shortcut, it opens under windows.

Fundamentally I would like to have gmusicbrowser display in front of all other windows when running `gmusicbrowser -cmd ShowHide` via a keyboard shortcut, as it does when running directly from the terminal.

Ubuntu version: 20.04
Cinnamon version: 5.0.5

Comment: You did include the Unity tag. Is there something specific to the Unity desktop in this question? You better also specify your Ubuntu version and desktop that you use in the question itself. Also, you are asking this as an XY question. Your problem seems that the app does not come to the front, and you ask about what you think will be the solution (running "via a terminal without actually opening one". Perhaps, there are other and better ways to your real problem, so ask about that real problem instead.

Comment: Thank you @vanadium I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: If the `.desktop` launcher is called `gmusicbrowser.desktop` then you could try assigning the command `gtk-launch gmusicbrowser` to the shortcut key. This launches the app as if you would be clicking it in the application menu.